# javascript (jquery?) and operators not workng

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, size, operators

i'm having one problem with the javascript code.
i set the minimum post file size
my code is:

```
if(f.size >= 512)
upload_file(f);
```

i want to set the maximum size too,then added this

```
if(f.size >= 512 && f.size <= 1512)
upload_file(f);
```

but when i test the script only the minimum size work,i upload a 245B file will return error,but i upload a 10MB picture it successfully upload,anyone know what's wrong in the script?

Comment: No, jQuery does not define any operators

Comment: A 1kb size should *not* return an error, provided those numbers are in bytes, so your lower limit isn't working either.

Comment: It should work. Show us the whole/real script (there might be other errors) and debug the value of the `fileSize` property when uploading your 10MB pic

Comment: What is f? Seems logically correct.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're trying to do here as javascript has no access to client side files to check file size before upload, therefore this code seems a little moot.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can with the HTML5 file api http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/

Comment: It does seem to work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/DFYLZ/

Comment: I see no jQuery here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your 1kB file should NOT return an error, since 1024 > 512. [The file API returns filesizes in bytes](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-size).

I therefore assume there are other errors in your script, such as:

the property of the File API that returns the file size is called `size`, not `fileSize`.

Answer (score 0):

With your logic, you should never get an error at all, because you have no else condition and are throwing no exceptions. If any are thrown, they are thrown inside upload_file, which means the problem is elsewhere.

The code here will only run `upload_file` if your conditions are met, and do nothing if they are not, which is consistent with the results you are seeing. In fact, every time an exception is thrown, it indicates the condition **succeeded**, and was not false.

For example, there is an error when you pass it a file 1kb in size, which means that the condition was true, and `upload_file` got to bork on a file. In the 10Mb example, no error is thrown, because the file never gets passed through the faulty `upload_file` function.